# How to properly code this one to many relationship according to design

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, h2

Im having trouble coding the following design in Java with H2 Database, I think I succesfully did the relation of WeatherData table with Location, but im not being able to properly do so with WeatherData/WeatherDataTemperature relation (one to many), alot of trouble there because in the class WeatherDataTemperature Hibernate is making a must to add the primary key but as you can see in my model I don't have a primary key, this is just an exercise but im just blocked, been seeing Baeldung tutorial (https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) but still stuck, this is as far as I got but now I cant have many Temperatures assigned to WeatherData cause of the @Id thing is a primary key and ofcourse it can not be repeated, please help

[image: model]

I have the following classes:

**WeatherData**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class WeatherData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    LocalDate date;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Location location;
    // Here is the problem im having I think
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "weatherData")
    private java.util.Set<WeatherDataTemperature> weatherDataTemperature;

    WeatherData() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Location getLocationId() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public java.util.Set<WeatherDataTemperature> getWeatherDataTemperature() {
        return weatherDataTemperature;
    }

    public void setWeatherDataTemperature(java.util.Set<WeatherDataTemperature> weatherDataTemperature) {
        this.weatherDataTemperature = weatherDataTemperature;
    }

}
```

**Location**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    Double lat;
    Double lon;
    String city;
    String state;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "location")
    private WeatherData weatherData;

    Location() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public WeatherData getWeatherData() {
        return weatherData;
    }

    public void setWeatherData(WeatherData weatherData) {
        this.weatherData = weatherData;
    }

}
```

**WeatherDataTemperature**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class WeatherDataTemperature implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "weather_data_id", nullable = false)
    private WeatherData weatherData;
    Double temperature;

    WeatherDataTemperature() {

    }

    public WeatherData getWeatherData() {
        return weatherData;
    }

    public void setWeatherData(WeatherData weatherData) {
        this.weatherData = weatherData;
    }

    public Double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(Double temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**:

Is there a way to make it work like the design is sugesting? With no primary key on Temperature table, also here is a JSON of how it should look (temperature can have up to 4 different values stored for a singlle WeaterData):

```json
{
    "id": 37892,
    "date": "2020-09-15",
    "location": {
        "lat": 32.7767,
        "lon": 96.7970,
        "city": "Dallas",
        "state": "Texas"
    },
    "temperature": [
        89.7,
        84.3,
        91.2,
        93.1
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your weather data temperature table needs its own unique id primary key.  The weather data id field is a foreign key back to the weather data table.  The previous sentence is the main reason you don't name all your primary key fields id.  It's too confusing to us human readers.  The primary key should be the table name and id concatenated.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Hi dude thank you for your answer, I think the same, but the problem is I need to be able to make it work as the design I showing, is it possible to code it in Java like that or I MUST make this table has it own primary key? I will post and EDIT with what is supposed the JSON of a meteorologic weather data to look like after I have my model well coded

Comment: Every table in a relational database **must** have a unique primary key.  You don't have to display the primary key of a table in JSON.  It's actually better if your primary keys are kept secret from the users of your database.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Thank you, so much time without coding... Im talking with a frriend and he says that maybe with ElementCollection annotation hibernate can take care of it, what do you think?

Comment: I've never used Hibernate.  I've always coded plain JDBC.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc check my answer I just posted, apparently when using ElementCollection Hibernate understands I don't need a primary key for that table and it lets me insert as many as I want with the same weather_id but different temperatures. It was generated as I wanted it to be, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution to making this work exactly as the design wants it to, I had to use @ElementCollection like so:

**WeatherData**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class WeatherData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    LocalDate date;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    Location location;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Weather_Data_Temperature")
    private java.util.Set<Double> temperature;

    WeatherData() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Location getLocationId() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocationId(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

**Location class had no changes**

**WeatherDataTemperature Class dissapiars (not needed if using @ElementCollection)**

And so when running the project h2 database gets well generated like so:

[image: H2 Database]

Notice that I was able to insert two different temperatures but both have the same weather_data_id, just like the design is suggesting to be able to without the need of a primary key.